# ionic 2 datepicker disable specific dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, ionic2, ionic-native

I am new in Ionic 2. I am trying to disable specific dates using datepicker in my ionic 2 project. I am aware there is [native version](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/) and [ionic component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/). However, As far as I see from the document, all that I can do is to change format of the date as well as enable or disable future or past dates. Is there any way to disable specific dates just like jquery datepicker [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) function?